# Appending objects to a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to append to a list an object from the given value(amount) up to one. But the problem with what I have right now it that the Coin object can't be interpreted as an integer. Is there a workaround to the add_to_table method in order to achieve what is expected?

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, table=[]):
        """(Test, int) -> NoneType
        """
        self.table = [(0, []), (1, []), (2, [])]

    def add_to_table(self, amount):
        """(Test, int) -> NoneType

        Adds to the first table Coin(amount) to Coin(1)

        ex.

        [(0, [Coin(3), Coin(2), Coin(1)]), (1, []), (2, [])]

        """
        self.table[0][1].extend(reversed(range(Coin(1), Coin(amount + 1))))

class Coin:

    def __init__(self, length):
        """(Coin, int) -> NoneType
        """
        self.length = length
```

Expected output:

```
t1 = Test()
t1.table
[(0, []), (1, []), (2, [])]
t1.add_to_table(3)
t1.table
[(0, [Coin(3), Coin(2), Coin(1)]), (1, []), (2, [])]
```

Comment: Aside: even though you're not using the `table` parameter in `__init__` right now, setting the default like `table=[]` is going to get you into trouble down the road.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for why you generally don't want to use mutable default arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want, two changes appear necessary:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, table=[]):
        """(Test, int) -> NoneType
        """
        self.table = [(0, []), (1, []), (2, [])]

    def add_to_table(self, amount):
        """(Test, int) -> NoneType

        Adds to the first table Coin(amount) to Coin(1)

        ex.

        [(0, [Coin(3), Coin(2), Coin(1)]), (1, []), (2, [])]

        """
        self.table[0][1].extend([Coin(n) for n in range(amount, 0, -1)])

class Coin:

    def __init__(self, length):
        """(Coin, int) -> NoneType
        """
        self.length = length

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Coin(%s)' % (self.length,)
```

The first change is that, to generate the range of values for Coin, the add_to_table method above uses list comprehension:  `[Coin(n) for n in range(amount, 0, -1)]`.  The second change is because you wanted the Coin list to display as `[Coin(3), Coin(2), Coin(1)]`.  The method `__repr__` controls how a class is displayed.  So this method was added to `Coin`.  With these two changes, the above yields:

```
>>> t1 = Test()
>>> t1.table
[(0, []), (1, []), (2, [])]
>>> t1.add_to_table(3)
>>> t1.table
[(0, [Coin(3), Coin(2), Coin(1)]), (1, []), (2, [])]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def add_to_table(self, amount):
    for i in range(amount, 0, -1):
        self.table[0][1].append(Coin(i))
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what your code is doing and how you came up with it to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Its not clear if you want the table to have the actual `Coin` objects, or the values of the objects; here I'm assuming its the values.*

You need to have a method that returns the value of your `Coin` objects. If you just add them to a list a special representation of your object (returned by the `__repr__` method) is used:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> [Foo(),Foo()]
[<__main__.Foo object at 0x20b44d0>, <__main__.Foo object at 0x20b4510>]
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "I am a Foo object"
... 
>>> [Foo(), Foo()]
[I am a Foo object, I am a Foo object]
```

However, the `__repr__` method should be used to return a string *representation* of the object, its not for returning meaningful values, in other words, its not the solution here.

You need to have a method in `Coin` to return the value of the coin, then use that value when you pass it to `Table`:

```
class Coin(object):
    ''' A coin object with a length '''

    def __init__(self, length):
        self._length = length

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length
```

Now, you need to do this:

```
coins = [Coin(1), Coin(2)]
table = Test()
for coin in coins:
    table.add_to_table(coin.length)
```

I am using the [`@property` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to make life easier.

You still have to make sure that the coins were created with integers and not strings, in other words `Coin('1')` will work perfectly fine, but your `add_to_table` method will raise an exception.